# Rails 4 Error: NoMethodError - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am struggling ordering my loop through my Devise Users by the upvotes on `tools` created by them.

Inside of that loop I get the value I would like to use to order the elments with:

```
user.tools.map(&:cached_votes_up).sum
```

That's my loop:

```
- @users.order(user.tools.map(&:cached_votes_up).sum).each do |user| #incorrect!
```

And my controller:

```
@users = User.all
```

Without `order` in my loop everything runs fine, with it this error appears:

```
NoMethodError in Users#index
Showing c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/app/views/users/index.html.haml where line #21 raised:

undefined method `tools' for #<Class:0xac2db78>
```

I am grateful for each help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `joins`

```
@users = User.joins(:tools).group("users.id").order("SUM(tools.cached_votes_up)")
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as possible :)